# Why isn't my jQuery toggleClass working?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm practically new to jQuery and I'm having trouble enlarging an image to 100% of it's size on click. I've looked the small bit of code over numerous times and it seems like that's how it should be. Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.gallery').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('enlarge');
    });
});
```

The CSS:

```
    img.gallery {
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        width: 260px;
        height: 260px;
    }

    .enlarge {
        width: auto;
    }
```

Am I linking to the library and scripts properly?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery.js"></script>
```

The full CSS without the snippet above is here: http://ruzzio.net/style.css

I'm wondering if something in the CSS is keeping the images from enlarging on click (assuming my jQuery is accurate).

Thanks for the help in advance guys. This is my first time using this site, if I forgot some crucial information, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img.gallery` has a higher specificity than `.enlarge` (0011 vs. 0010) therefore it will be considered more important.

Try removing the `img` tag name. CSS selectors should be as simple as necessary.

Comment: I did and it's still not working. It's so frustrating and I'm sure it's something simple that I've either overlooked or am unaware of lol.

Comment: Actually it is working. I had to remove img AND utilize delroh's answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying the following if you are unsure about the right width set in CSS:

```
.enlarge {
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

you'll see if the toggle works fine ;-)

Comment: I appreciate the response. I got it working now thanks to Niet and delroh!

Answer (score 0):

Because `auto` won't make it grow in size. The `auto` value, simply put, automatically calculates and sets the size of the element, not extend it to the container. Asuming your images are inside a container, try:

```
   img.gallery {
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        width: 260px;
        height: 260px;
    }

    .gallery.enlarge {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/gfW3g/1/

Edit: added example and fixed css for specificity

Comment: This is working. I had to use both your answer and Niet's lol. Thank you!

Comment: I added a working example and added the gallery class for css specificity. As Niet said, it is not necessary to have img.gallery, and it will limit the use of the class to just img elements. I am glad I could help you.